# Functional way to create new list by processing elements of another list?

Tags: python, list

What is the simplest way of creating one list from another?

Suppose I have a list of filenames and wish to create correspondent list of objects

```
ans = []
  for filename in filenames:
    ans.append( myreadfunction(filename) )
```

Is there more "functional" way?

Comment: If you want functional, why not `map`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the simplest way of creating one list from another?

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
ans = [myreadfunction(filename) for filename in filenames]
```

Comment: What if processing is not encapsulated into a function? Can I have "global" `for filename`?

Comment: @Dims That's a different question.

Comment: @chepner not a different; I am just asking not to stuck to single-liners

Answer (score 4):

If you want functional use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map):

```
ans = list(map(myreadfunction,filenames))
```